# Why can not pass the validation of type of the series

Tags: python, pandas

I do not know why it can not pass the validation of each variable.

```
marvel_df = rate_df.loc[rate_df['Company']== "Marvel"]
mean_marvel =marvel_df[['Rate']].mean()
std_marvel =marvel_df[['Rate']].std()
n_marvel = marvel_df[['Rate']].count()

dc_df = rate_df.loc[rate_df['Company']== "DC"]
mean_dc =dc_df[['Rate']].mean()
std_dc =dc_df[['Rate']].std()
n_dc =dc_df[['Rate']].count()

# Validation
assert n_marvel == 23
assert n_dc == 16
assert np.ndim(mean_marvel) == np.ndim(mean_dc) == np.ndim(std_marvel) == np.ndim(std_dc) == np.ndim(n_marvel) == np.ndim(n_dc)
```

Comment: Remove the `.loc` and try again.  That probably is the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with this cleaned up code:

```
marvel_df = rate_df[rate_df['Company'] == "Marvel"]
mean_marvel = marvel_df['Rate'].mean()
std_marvel = marvel_df['Rate'].std()
n_marvel = marvel_df['Rate'].count()

dc_df = rate_df[rate_df['Company'] == "DC"]
mean_dc = dc_df['Rate'].mean()
std_dc = dc_df['Rate'].std()
n_dc = dc_df['Rate'].count()
```

Answer (score 0):

`marvel_df[['Rate']].count()` gives you a `pd.Series` with one element, namely the count of the non-`NaN` values in the `Rate` column of `marvel_df`. `n_marvel == 23` returns a `pd.Series` of boolean values, again with only one entry - but the truth value of a Series is ambiguous.

Comment: Is that only because of the double `[[]]`? Because the return of `pd.Series.count()` is an `int`. [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.count.html)

Comment: Yes, but `marvel_df[['Rate']]` is a `pd.DataFrame`, not a `pd.Series` - so correspondingly when applying `.count()`, you also get a `pd.Series` instead of `int`.

Comment: Okay, that's what I was asking. Does `marvel_df[['Rate']]` make a `pd.DataFrame`, because `marvel_df['Rate']` makes a `pd.Series`.